# Digital audio input on Macbook?

Tags: macbook, audio-recording, input, digital-audio

I have:

- a Macbook (not Pro), don't know the exact model but it's a Core 2 Duo 2.0GHz and probably what Wikipedia calls the "Late 2006" or "Mid 2007" model
- a DVD player, region-free, that has "Coax and TosLink optical digital audio outputs"

I want to make an MP3 of the audio track of some DVDs (for learning a new language), and I can't use the Macbook's built-in DVD drive because it's a different region (ugh!).  I'm sure I can connect the DVD player to the Macbook with an analog audio cable.  However, if it's possible I'd prefer to keep the signal digital.

I'm not even positive if my old Macbook *has* digital audio in, and if so what I need to connect to it.  (I've done plenty of home audio geeking, but always in analog!)

Will a "Toslink cable" plus a "Toslink Female to Mini-Plug Male Adapter" (found on Amazon) let me connect my things together?  It looks like the pieces will fit but I'd like to hear someone confidently knowledgeable on the matter before I buy something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your MacBook has a female TOSLINK mini-plug which will allow you to input digital audio into your MacBook. I use this same strategy, but to output audio to my home theatre setup. You  will be fine with the female TOSLINK to male TOSLINK mini-plug adapter. (And it's not just Wikipedia that calls it *Late 2006* or *Mid 2007*; those are Apple's names!)